# Length of vowels before ‘ss’ in Swiss standard German

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, swiss-standard-german, vowel-length

In standard German (of Germany and Austria) we use the spelling difference between *ss* and *ß* to signal whether the preceding vowel is short or long. A short vowel is followed by *ss,* a long vowel is followed by *ß.*

In Swiss standard German (N.B. I really mean *Swiss standard German* here, and not Swiss German), there is no *ß* letter, and words which would include it in Germany and Austria are always spelt with *ss.*

Is this just an orthographic fact, or does it also mean that the vowel before *ss* is always short? In other words, in Swiss standard German, would you read *Strasse* with a long or short *a?*

Comment: Only in case you are not aware of that: It is perfectly fine to ask questions in German here.

Comment: Your assumption is not correct. `ss` and `ß` are not used to indicate whether the preceding vowel is short or long (even though you can guess from that). Rather, it is the other way: the length of the preceding vowel decides whether you need to use `ss` or `ß`, which is an important difference and already answers your question. In "de-DE" German, the decision is `short vowel => ss, long vowel => ß`. As there **is no ß** in "de-CH" German, the decision is `short vowel => ss, long vowel => ss`. The problem is the other direction. Does *Massen* refer to *Massen* or *Maßen*?

Comment: @CarstenS: I know, thanks, but unfortunately my German is not good enough, for now. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thankfully, Swiss Radio and Television ([Schweizer Radio und Fernsehen, SRF](http://www.srf.ch)) have audio and video news available online. These news broadcasts are often spoken in Swiss standard German rather than in Swiss dialects. I opened the [first article I saw](http://www.srf.ch/news/schweiz/internes-eu-dokument-kommt-in-bern-schlecht-an) and listened in until I heard a word that would be written with *ß* in German. Well, to be honest, I waited for two words, as the first one was *Massnahmen* and there is no clear difference between long and short *a* (the feature the same vowel sound but in different quantity; all other quantity differences except for long *ä* also feature a different *quality).*

The word I heard was *Verstoss* as written in the article. The *o* in *Verstoss* was clearly a long one ([oː], not [ɔ]).

Thus, it is a purely orthographic feature that *does not* influence pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

Although I know it's not always the most accurate resource, the [Wikipedia article on Swiss Standard German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_Standard_German) says:

> The Swiss keyboard layout has no ß key, nor does it have the capital
>   umlaut keys Ä, Ö and Ü. This dates back to mechanical typewriters that
>   had the French diacritical marks letters on these keys to allow the
>   Swiss to write French on a Swiss German QWERTZ keyboard (and vice
>   versa).

And that is what I've also been taught during my German lessons in Switzerland.

**Conclusion:** the use of `ss` instead of `ß` is caused by mere technical reason and has no influence on the pronunciation of the words.

Comment: Your conclusion is right, but today Ä, Ö and Ü can be produced on a Swiss German keyboard using Caps Lock.